# How to find out which post I got the 'Peer Pressure' badge for?

Tags: support, badges, deleted-questions

I came back from a group meeting at the pub last night. When I woke up this morning I found I have the Peer Pressure badge, which I'm not sure I want but keep getting... (even for a good question that's down-voted for questionable (or non-questionable if you'll pardon the linguistic inversion; often it's to do with anon trolls I have counter-trolled in the past, if you'll pardon the digression) reasons I'm not sure if it's a good one...?)

But anyway, yeah, how do I find out which deleted question the troll badge was awarded for?

Answer (score 5):

You made it sound like you get this badge all the time; it should only be awardable once. You got it when ['403 Forbidden' error only appears on Linux system; other devices connect fine from same IP address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277463/403-forbidden-error-only-appears-on-linux-system-other-devices-connect-fine-f) was automatically deleted as part of a [daily cleanup routine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) (it falls under the last category). I think this might actually be a bug, since Peer Pressure is supposed to be for deleting your own post; you shouldn't get it when the system deletes it for you

Comment: I get it awarded on many different forums. I Meta Stack Exchange and get followed from there. Is it 'might be' a bug or not? Was this by design or accident?

Comment: When a question is deleted automatically, the answers are marked as being deleted by the poster. This is a know bug(?), there's been a post on [meta.se] which I'm too lazy too look up.

Comment: @muru True, although I don't think that matters here, since it was a question deletion that awarded the badge. The question shows up as deleted by Community, but somehow the badge was awarded anyway

Answer (score 0):

You might find it in the ["All Actions"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138973/peter-david-carter?tab=activity&sort=all) tab under your profile. I don't see this record there, but it might not be public.

Otherwise you, should be able to see it in [Reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138973/peter-david-carter?tab=reputation) tab, if you check "show removed posts".

Comment: The tab only yields: 5h
awarded  Peer Pressure
12h
awarded  Explainer :/

Comment: You should also be able to see it in reputation change. You don't have too much posts :)

Comment: I can see an overall positive rep change, and that's nice but I wanted to find the post itself, not that my rep got better overall.

Comment: If you select "post" view, you will see the reputation breakdown by post.

Comment: As I said, it's not the rep I'm interested in. I want to find the post. I want knowledge of the post, not knowledge of my rep which I know already.

Comment: Deleting negative reputation post, results in positive reputation. It is how it works. These things are related. It would be certainly nice to see it directly next to the badge, but it is not the case as you already noticed.

Comment: Flagged your answer as not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for appreciation the attempt to help.

Comment: You didn't attempt to help. I did everything you said and nothing worked. It's just like what you did when I was attempting to install Fedora. You pretended to help but nothing ever got fixed and you offer no real answers. You knew it wouldn't work.